# Developing a server to host a smartphone app content

Tags: android, python, ios, unity-game-engine

Im building this app (using Unity3d) for a city hall and I need to split the content from the actual app since content must be easily changeable without having to update the app itself.

I want to host the content on a server and use http get/post messages to retrieve the data. I also need to have a web editor (kinda like a CMS) so that the client can change the content himself.

In the editor I would just have a list of "rooms", where each "room" would be one of three types (i.e. text screen, slideshow or audio). Depending on what type the room is, different parameters should be visible and editable.

What language you suggest I write the server in? (the server that the app would contact in order to obtain the up-to-date content) Python i'm guessing here?

What would be the easiest way to build the browser editor? Javascript and django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know Python already and don't want to have to support maintaining a web server for your client it would probably be easy to host the web portion of your app on Google's App Engine. It's relatively easy to use App Engine to serve a simple a web form where the client could edit content and upload binaries.  The form could be built using Jinja or Django-style templates, and the data would be written to App Engine's datastore. (also, it's easy to restrict access to the form to app administrators to prevent accidental/malicious edits)

Then the Unity app would query a page on the App Engine server to see if there's new content using the WWW object. The server would make a quick memcache/datastore query and return a JSON response telling Unity if there's more stuff to download or not.

I've done all of this in past projects, so I'm sure it's workable, and a lot of relevant code can be found in [App Engine's tutorials](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction) and via some light Googling.

Answer (score 1):

I would also look at [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/) as a CMS. You can create custom forms for different post types. Each "room" type could also be a category type and have custom fields for data to be inputed.

There are loads of plugins to get up and running without too much coding. But you can also dig in and customize with some PHP coding.

The great thing about Wordpress is that media handling, Database interface, user management, privilege and editorial controls, to hand off to a client, are all there. There are loads of tutorials and [documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/) to get the platform to work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Android get connected easily  with cloud server.I don't know about others. You can connect using JSON and PHP for this.

Comment: My issue is not really with connecting android to whatever server since all I need to do is the http call to get the data. My question was more about how should I implement the server + editor :)

Comment: you can connect that server with Web application which can update information for admin and same you can use for your app.which type of data you want on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use .net platform as an backend server.

Answer (score 0):

You could also build Webservices. On my project we work with it. You could also do it with PHP. Try this link: [Androidhive.info/how-to-connect-android-with-php](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)